# Dealing with nested parenthesis in regex

Tags: java, regex

I would like my regex to match when there is a complete set of nested parenthesis of max depth 5. My current code is working but it has an awful time complexity and takes very long for long sets of parenthesis.

```
^((\\((\\((\\((\\((\\(\\))*\\)(\\(\\))*)*\\))*\\))*(\\((\\((\\((\\(\\))*\\)(\\(\\))*)*\\))*\\))*\\))*)$
```

Example:

```
String s = (()());
System.out.println(s.matches(...));
```

-->
prints True.

```
String s = ()));
System.out.println(s.matches(...));
```

-->
prints False.

How can I change my current code so that it is not only more efficient but also a bit easier to read?
Note that I do want this done in regex and that I know it's very simple to do with for loops. 
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you particularly want it done in regex?  This is the sort of problem that is better solved with other mechanisms.  Regexes cannot solve all the world's problems.

Comment: You want to use a grammar engine there. For instance, [grappa](https://github.com/fge/grappa) can tackle this problem for you.

Comment: I'm just currently trying to get a better understanding of how to use regex and this was a problem I thought could be a bit tricky yet solvable.

Comment: Your problem is that you're using Regex

Comment: I think you accomplished that.  It's tricky, and you solved it.  You also found that the solution is unreadable and slow.  So there's your better understanding.  Mission Accomplished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only looking for a maximum depth of 5 then you can use the following regexp

```
(\((\((\((\((\(\))*\))*\))*\))*\))*
```

You can preveiw the results here http://regex101.com/r/zN1sZ2/1

As a bonus here is some psuedo code you can use to generate this string

```
var s = "_", depth = 5;
while(depth > 0) {
    s = s.replace("_", "(\\(_\\))*");
    depth--;
}
s = s.replace("_", "");
```

Now it as simple as changing one variable (`depth`) if your needs change and using the string `s` to perform your regexp

Comment: +1. You can also speed it up quite a lot across multiple matches by compiling the regex once rather than over and over: `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(thatRegex);` and then  `pattern.matcher(string).matches()` rather than `string.matches(thatRegex)`.

Comment: (Wow, I now can post comments!) Your expression is very likely what @aliasTrebut intended to code, but I took the liberty to replace all escaped '(' by a and all ')' by b to make it more readable. The original regexp turns to ^((a(a(a(a(ab)*b(ab)*)*b)*b)*(a(a(a(ab)*b(ab)*)*b)*b)*b)*)$ whereas yours turns to (a(a(a(a(ab)*b)*b)*b)*b)*

Comment: yes, he asked for more efficient, easier to read code and it doesn't get much better than what I provided, especially with the included code to generate the regex.

Answer (score 2):

Strict regular expressions ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression ) can't do this.
Real life programming languages all have "extended" regular expressions, more or less at cost of performance.

What you need (in terms of math) is a push down automaton ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton ).

Comment: Strict regular expressions can do this, because there's a specified max depth.

Comment: well, they can, if you have a max depth

Comment: Well, right, if there is a limit on the max depth, a finite automaton can do. But, have a lot of fun spending the time between now and Christmas constructing that expression ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are going way beyond 5 levels.
When formatted, it should form a shape like a `>` symbol
5 levels deep.

Beyond that, you should make the outer parenthesis non-optional.
( here, Formatted and Tested with [RegexFormat 5](http://www.regexformat.com) )

```
 #  "(\\((\\((\\((\\((\\(\\))*\\))*\\))*\\))*\\))"

 #^ 
 (                             # (1 start)
      \(
      (                             # (2 start)
           \(
           (                             # (3 start)
                \(
                (                             # (4 start)
                     \(
                     (                             # (5 start)
                          \(\)
                     )*                            # (5 end)
                     \)
                )*                            # (4 end)
                \)
           )*                            # (3 end)
           \)
      )*                            # (2 end)
      \)
 )                             # (1 end)
 # $
```

Output Sample:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 63 , len 20 ) 
(()()()()((()()())))  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 63 , len 20 ) 
(()()()()((()()())))  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 63 , len 20 ) 
(()()()()((()()())))  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 72 , len 10 ) 
((()()()))  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 73 , len 8 ) 
(()()())  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 78 , len 2 ) 
()
```

If you introduce cluster groups for the repetition, you can capture
more of the inner level contents.
Won't be able to do it in its entirety,  possibly using C# with its
capture collections it could be done.

```
 #  "(\\(((?:\\(((?:\\(((?:\\(((?:\\(\\))*)\\))*)\\))*)\\))*)\\))"

 #^ 
 (                             # (1 start)
      \(

      (                             # (2 start)
           (?:
                \(
                (                             # (3 start)
                     (?:
                          \(
                          (                             # (4 start)
                               (?:
                                    \(
                                    (                             # (5 start)
                                         (?:
                                              \(\)
                                         )*
                                    )                             # (5 end)
                                    \)
                               )*
                          )                             # (4 end)
                          \)
                     )*
                )                             # (3 end)
                \)
           )*
      )                             # (2 end)
      \)
 )                             # (1 end)
 # $
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 3 , len 42 ) 
((()()()()((()()())))(()()()()((()()()))))  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 3 , len 42 ) 
((()()()()((()()())))(()()()()((()()()))))  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 4 , len 40 ) 
(()()()()((()()())))(()()()()((()()())))  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 25 , len 18 ) 
()()()()((()()()))  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 34 , len 8 ) 
(()()())  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 35 , len 6 ) 
()()()
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily done using an inside-out methodology. Here is a regex which efficiently matches an innermost pair of matching parentheses:

### regex to match innermost parentheses pair

`\([^()]*\)`

And here is a tested JavaScript function which iteratively applies the above regex to strip out all matching pairs from the inside out, while counting the nesting level as it goes:

```js
function isBalanced5deeporLess(text) {
    var depth = 0;
    var re_inner_paren = /\([^()]*\)/g;
    while (text.search(re_inner_paren) !== -1) {
        text = text.replace(re_inner_paren, '');
        depth++;    // count nesting depth level.
    }
    if (text.length === 0 && depth <= 5) { return true; }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, the required nesting depth is easily modified to suit. I'm not really a Java guy, but this logic should be easily translated.